# Running an admin task from a windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows Service from which I have to run a process. However, that process requires admin privileges to run. Inside `Process Explorer`, I see that the service does run the process but the UI for that process does not appear up.

What am I missing here? How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The services run in a separate session, with a separate desktop. Think of it as if the services where running in another remote desktop session. Anything with a GUI that you start from within a service will be shown in that hidden session, which cannot be accessed.

Comment: So, can I run another console exe from the windows service, which on running will run the desktop application/

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Everything originating from the services will be trapped inside the service session. What is the problem you're trying to solve? What kind of program are you starting and why are you starting it from a service?

Comment: Unfortunately, the application that I have to start is a desktop application and requires admin previliges because I am setting up a local server inside this application. This service was built to keep checking if this desktop application is running. If not, run the application.

Comment: So, instead of the service, should I build a console application with the same logic (just that it's not service) and then start this application from there. (Instead of the service running on restart, I will schedule this console application to run at restart)

Comment: That's a better idea, to use an application that auto-starts on login. If you make the application with a hidden GUI and a tray icon it will be less intrusive to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on Windows Vista or 7, services can't interact with desktop like windows XP and they can't open a window like ordinary windows applications. They default run as Local System account which is a fully privileged account.

Comment: So, even if I mandate administraotr previliges for my windows serivce, it won't open the process' window? the process is already running inside process explorer, just that it is not showing its default windows

Comment: It will start the process, but you will see the window in a different environment. You can use another process which is a windows application to open the process for you. It can be notified using a pipe or socket by the service. I think this is why all applications which need Update Apps or another app launching, they have an icon in notification area which is the launcher part.